# Render :edit not working as expected with turbo frame

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo-rails

I am developing a 2-step booking form using turbo-rails in order to use Ajax and update only the necessary page components.
I am using 2 models, `BookingDate` and `Booking`. `BookingDate` contains the start and end DateTimes. `Booking` contains the `BookingDate` and the other booking attributes.
The application consists in a single page. The idea is this: after the user chooses the dates and presses `Next Step`, the app saves the `BookingDate` record, still displays the date pickers enabled (in edit mode), and shows the items available for those dates.
**The problem is**: I am not able to display the editable date pickers after saving the dates. Instead, the app shows the booking_dates/index page.

**views/cust/customer_bookings/_main.html.erb**

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag @booking_date do %>
  <%= render "booking_dates/cust_form", booking_date: @booking_date %>
<% end %>
```

**views/bookings_dates/_cust_form.html.erb**

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag @booking_date do %>
  <%= simple_form_for(@booking_date) do |f| %>
    <%= f.date_field :start_date %>
    <%= f.date_field :end_date %>
    <%= f.submit value = "Next step" %>
<% end %>
```

**controllers/booking_dates_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @booking_date = BookingDate.new(booking_date_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @booking_date.save
        format.html { render :edit, location: @booking_date }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @booking_date }
      else
        ...
      end
    end
  end
```

**views/booking_dates/_edit.html.erb**

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag @booking_date do %>
  <%= render "booking_dates/cust_form", booking_date: @booking_date %>
<% end %>
```

**Server log:**

```
Started POST "/booking_dates" for ::1 at 2023-02-27 18:53:58 +0100
Processing by BookingDatesController#create as TURBO_STREAM
...
app/controllers/booking_dates_controller.rb:46:in `block in create'
TRANSACTION (93.7ms)  commit transaction
↳ app/controllers/booking_dates_controller.rb:46:in `block in create'
Rendering booking_dates/edit.html.erb
Rendered booking_dates/_cust_form.html.erb (Duration: 3.2ms | Allocations: 1042)
Rendered booking_dates/edit.html.erb (Duration: 4.2ms | Allocations: 1217)
Completed 200 OK in 110ms (Views: 5.6ms | ActiveRecord: 94.5ms | Allocations: 4237)
Started GET "/booking_dates" for ::1 at 2023-02-27 09:17:18 +0100
```

For the use of turbo frames I am using this tutorial:
[Hotrails - Turbo Rails tutorial](https://www.hotrails.dev/turbo-rails)

Comment: You never render a body and send a `Location` header in the same response. What's the point of sending an entire page if you're also telling the client to redirect?

Comment: Aha, I misunderstood the location option, I thought it was used for sending the object to the next view, instead it's redirecting. However, after deleting the location option, the result looks the same

Comment: You may be thinking of `locals:` which is used to [pass local assigns to a view](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables).

Comment: @max changed to `format.html { render partial: "cust_form", locals: {booking_date: @booking_date } }` . Apparently nothing is changing, the page redirects after saving,  Adding the first part of the log

Comment: I don't think this is actually rendering the view that you think it is. `render :edit` will render `edit.html.erb` not `_edit.html.erb` which is a partial by convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by doing the following:

1. As suggested in the comment, changed the controller's edit action to: `format.html { render :edit, status: :ok, locals: {booking_date: @booking_date } }`
2. In `edit.html.erb`, changed the turbo_fram_tag to "new_booking_date". For me, this was the bug most difficult to spot: after persisting the object, the previous code `turbo_frame_tag @booking_date` was pointing to the persisted object, therefore breaking the logic of having a turbo frame with the same id "new_booking_date"